# comparative matrix into percentage in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, vector

I have created a matrix that compares strings of vectors within a list to each other.

```
sapply(names(setlist), function(x) sapply(names(setlist), function(y) sum(setlist[[x]] %in% setlist[[y]])))


              A             B             C              D 
A             50            1             0              0   
B             1             6             0              0
C             0             0             51             8
D             0             0             8              46
```

For example the number of strings within vector A and vector B that are the exact same are 1, with 50 total strings in A and 6 within B.

I would like to normalize the data so that, using the example above. The total stings of A and B is 56, so divide 1 by 56 = .018. The end result should look something like this:

```
              A             B             C              D 
A             .5            .018          0              0   
B             .018          .5            0              0
C             0             0             .5             .082
D             0             0             .082           .5
```

Comment: How does this normalization work? Why diagonal after normalization is 1? I thought you should either normalize all values (so A-A is 0,082), or normalize by row/column (so A-B is 1/51 = 0,0196).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#DATA
m = structure(c(50L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 51L, 8L, 
0L, 0L, 8L, 46L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", 
"C", "D"), c("A", "B", "C", "D")))
```

Use `sapply` to go through each column and normalize

```
sapply(X = 1:NCOL(m), function(i) round(x = m[,i]/(m[i,i]+diag(m)), digits = 3))
#   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
#A 0.500 0.018 0.000 0.000
#B 0.018 0.500 0.000 0.000
#C 0.000 0.000 0.500 0.082
#D 0.000 0.000 0.082 0.500
```

You could substitute 1 in the diagonal elements with `replace`

```
sapply(X = 1:NCOL(m), function(i)
    replace(x = round(x = m[,i]/(m[i,i]+diag(m)), digits = 3),
            list = i,
            values = 1))
#   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
#A 1.000 0.018 0.000 0.000
#B 0.018 1.000 0.000 0.000
#C 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.082
#D 0.000 0.000 0.082 1.000
```

Comment: Excellent, this worked. How would you keep the headers the same as A,B,C,D instead of the [,1],[,2],[,3],[,4]?

Comment: You could copy the names from `dimnames(m)[[2]]`